# Extract only specific information using OCR and OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, ocr, information-retrieval

I am trying to get specific information from a bill. I have used ocr till now and OpenCV and here are the results:

```
import cv2 
import pytesseract
import numpy as np

image = cv2.imread('1.png')

# get grayscale image
def get_grayscale(image):
return cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# noise removal
def remove_noise(image):
return cv2.medianBlur(image,5)

#thresholding
def thresholding(image):
return cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

#dilation
def dilate(image):
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
return cv2.dilate(image, kernel, iterations = 1)

#erosion
def erode(image):
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
return cv2.erode(image, kernel, iterations = 1)

#opening - erosion followed by dilation
def opening(image):
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
return cv2.morphologyEx(image, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

#canny edge detection
def canny(image):
return cv2.Canny(image, 100, 200)

#skew correction
def deskew(image):
coords = np.column_stack(np.where(image > 0))
angle = cv2.minAreaRect(coords)[-1]
if angle < -45:
    angle = -(90 + angle)
else:
    angle = -angle
(h, w) = image.shape[:2]
center = (w // 2, h // 2)
M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)
rotated = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w, h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_REPLICATE)
return rotated

#template matching
def match_template(image, template):
return cv2.matchTemplate(image, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED) 


gray = get_grayscale(image)
thresh = thresholding(gray)
opening = opening(gray)
canny = canny(gray)
cv2.imshow('res', gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Adding custom options
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
custom_config = r'--oem 3 --psm 6'
pytesseract.image_to_string(gray, config=custom_config)
```

the output I got was

```
Out[9]: 'aso en bosaanes sosesoen\nSee arr ee\n[internationale Spedition “works carrier:\nree Meese 
Eaton oro\nSE Eesn Srey alata ascea\ntay See eae ror\nTBlaecaseew £2 saserzaz9gn [acs Sue Saeeats 
Arve\noricore toptetschlBve ta\nbares eye creat tere\nLene et aan Ease\ncoon soos\nreaee\nbenenter 
petachand AiG & co. x8\nese See ete Fests\nsee Sse\npearson | |\nen 7\nFeanséurt an main bawegoansn 
|\npe |\nsor per tantace e/ear0003537\nEl = T=] | = [== |\nSta psa a4 fonstsanern\nLerper 
atcnen\nwe\n20 ocd hoes ale 22ers wf\n30 ped londed on pwc aoasonnr #0\n35 ped londed on pwc 2008es00 
#0\n64 pcs loaded on| PMC BO3BBART MD &\n[ental — |\n=\n|\nSJ |] Spscrinan copnapen as wtshan momen 
ante\nart veins otetrich cata 60. RAS sem\n[re ote\n[\\gesoago |__| tars ena Detrich ea\nTon anine 
Setrion cn a co. eta a5 scan\nSS aan ee ee\nee eS] - 
esemen\ncision\n\x0c'
```

I need specific information only like the name, shipping address, quantity, etc, and not all the characters. Also, the output is all mashed up. Can anyone please help me with this? any code or any other help would be appreciated.

[image: Input Image]

Comment: show the input image, make clear what information you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pytesseract.image_to_pdf_or_hocr()`](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/), choosing `hocr` as output format. This will contain bounding boxes on the character, word, and line level.